# do while loop to ask for positive input and less than 10

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I'm new to C and I was asked to make a loop that asks a user to input a number and then check if that number is positive and less than 10. However, I don't know what's wrong with the code below. Any help is much appreciated.

```
int main(){
int a;

do{
    printf("Enter a positive number: ");
    scanf("%i", &a);
}while((a <= 0) && (a >= 10));

    printf("%i is positive and less than 10", a);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please change `while((a <= 0) && (a >= 10))` to `while((a <= 0) || (a >= 10))`

Comment: You do not need a do while loop for this task. and the condition is wrong.

Comment: @XXDIL Please elaborate. Surely there are alternative loop types, but you do not mean that specifically a do-while is not needed. I assume you mean "no loop is needed" and I cannot agree with that.

Comment: You almost certainly never want to use `%i` in scanf! Unless you really want input `015` to equal thirteen...

Comment: You should not ask for a logic change in your program. Please develop your logic by yourself.

Comment: @Yunnosch, I meant there are better loops for this task. like a simple while. Anyway it doesnt matter there are a lot of uncertainity with this Question.

Comment: @XXDIL I even diagree with that. The chosen loop is appropriate for a condition based on something which is only meaningful after the first iteration and reading the code this way better matches the logic.

Comment: I see what you mean but if the task is to get input till the input matches a specific format(say between 0 - 10) then a while is sufficient. Do while is more useful in the case of a menu driven progam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that need fixing:

- You're not checking that `scanf()`  succeeds. I/O is brittle and can fail.
- The condition is wrong, both branches of the `&&` cannot be true at the same time, thus "and" is the wrong operator. You meant `||` (boolean "or").

Comment: I  reflexively started to comment "please explain" because I was deceived by the shortness of your post. But reading closely I see that all sensible explanation is in there. ;-) Kind of the problem my teachers had with my essays.... I once got full marks for four lines, when the expectation was one page (teacher) and ten pages (class mates). Cheers.

Comment: I now see the problem. I am still quite new to programming and your help is very much appreciated. Thanks!